# View Pan Gesture stops when the translation is shown in a Label - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, label, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm just creating a pan gesture to move an Image in Xcode. I want that the translation appear in a label while the UIView is being moved. For that I wrote the following code:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    // Pan Move

    static CGPoint initialCenter;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        initialCenter = recognizer.view.center;
    }

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(initialCenter.x + translation.x,
                                     initialCenter.y + translation.y);

    self.labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", translation.x];
}
```

As soon as the translation is assigned to the label, the View goes back to the origin.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a special site that you can recommend me where I can get that kind of standard block of codes?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you right now with your pan recognizer problem but I can give you two sites that I usually use to find solutions according to what I'm looking for.

[CocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/)

and

[Code4app](http://code4app.net/)

Hope you can find there something related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your handlePan() method:

```
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
```

ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/setTranslation:inView:

Comment: I just try it but it still doesn't work :( 
With that line of code, nothing moves at it override the coordinates of the view always to 0,0